# array filtering of prime numbers with fat arrows

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Learning how to incorporate fat arrows to write some clever array filtering.

```
const newArray = [1, 3, 2, 5, 10];
const isPrime = num => {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) return false;
  }
  return num !== 1;
};


const myPrimeArray = newArray.filter(element => isPrime(element));
console.log(myPrimeArray);
```

Is there a way I can incorporate the function isPrime into the fat arrow .filter inline?

Comment: It's not entirely clear (as you can see from the answers), did you want to remove the reference to `isPrime` so that the function is defined only inside the `.filter`, or did you want to remove the manual call of `isPrime(element)` inside the `.filter`?

Comment: Your code is fine as it is. `isPrime` is a reusable function. You could probably move it to a separate `utils` module and `import` it wherever you need it. Any more changes to this code will be trivial and possibly make it hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the function *reference* instead of calling it within an anonymous function in  `filter()`

```
const myPrimeArray = newArray.filter(isPrime);
```

Regardless of being written as an arrow function or not the end result is it is still just a function object

Answer (score 1):

Just copy and paste the body of `isPrime` into the `filter` callback:

```js
const newArray = [1, 3, 2, 5, 10];
const myPrimeArray = newArray.filter(num => {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) return false;
  }
  return num !== 1;
});
console.log(myPrimeArray);
```

But that's not so readable IMO - I prefer your version, named functions are nice for operations that aren't extremely trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The filter function accepts arrow function, or fat arrow function if you wish :

```
const myPrimeArray = newArray.filter(isPrime);
```

Working example :

```js
const newArray = [1, 3, 2, 5, 10];
const isPrime = num => {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) return false;
  }
  return num !== 1;
};


const myPrimeArray = newArray.filter(isPrime);
console.log(myPrimeArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the function `isPrime` in callback of `filter`

```js
const newArray = [1, 3, 2, 5, 10];


const myPrimeArray = newArray.filter(num => {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) return false;
  }
  return num !== 1;
});
console.log(myPrimeArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const newArray = [1, 3, 2, 5, 10];
const myPrimeArray = newArray.filter(element => {
    for (let i = 2; i < element; i++) {
        if (element % i === 0) return false;
    }
    return element !== 1;
});
console.log(myPrimeArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **point-free notation** ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming)), often used in functional programming, and omit the argument. Instead of giving an arrow function taking an argument and calling your `isPrime` function with that single argument, just pass your `isPrime` function:

`arg => isPrime(arg)` is equivalent to `isPrime`, so you can do this:

```
const myPrimeArray = newArray.filter(isPrime);
```

Or you can define your arrow function where it is used, as argument to your filter call. However, this code is **less readable and reusable** than defining an `isPrime` function as you did.

```js
const newArray = [1, 3, 2, 5, 10];

const myPrimeArray = newArray.filter(num => {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) return false;
  }
  return num !== 1 && num !== 0;
});

console.log(myPrimeArray);
```

> Warning: `isPrime(0)` should return false, add a condition at the end for that.

You can also decrease the complexity of the algorithm from `O(n)` to `O(sqrt(n))` and get the result faster if you only loop until the square root of the number:

```js
const newArray = [1, 3, 2, 5, 10];

const myPrimeArray = newArray.filter(num => {
  for (let i = 2, s = Math.sqrt(num); i <= s; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) return false;
  }
  return num !== 1 && num !== 0;
});

console.log(myPrimeArray);
```